# How do I import SQL file from a directory to a postgres database

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to import an sql file into my postgress database, this is the process am trying to use

```
You are now connected to database "test" as user "postgres".
test=# \i 'person.sql'
person.sql: No such file or directory
test=# \i person.sql
person.sql: No such file or directory
test=#
```

I have a person.sql file in a download folder, and I am trying to use it in the database called *test*

I have also tried

```
test=# \i home/camindo/Downloads/person.sql
postgres=#: No such file or directory
```

its still not working. I am working on linux fedora. Any ideas to make this thing work?

Comment: Does `\i /home/camindo/Downloads/person.sql` work?

Comment: What OS are you using at the moment? You might need to address the absolute path to the SQL file.

Comment: ```\i /home/camindo/Downloads/person.sql``` does not work, my computer OS is linux

Comment: Well, then obviously you did not store the SQL script in the folder you think you did. If the "downloads" folder is not your current directory when you start `psql` then you need to provide the full path to the file. But only you can find out what that path is exactly. The command **will** work if there is a file `/home/camindo/Downloads/person.sql` on your disk

Answer (score 1):

You can run this command on your terminal without logging into PSQL.

```
psql databasename < person.sql
```

Or

```
psql -h hostname -d databasename -U username -f path/to/folder/person.sql
```

Here hostname is the psql server, like `localhost`, the username is your Postgres username.
Please ensure you have created a database with the name `databasename` in PSQL.

Comment: ```[postgres@fedora ~]$ psql -h 5432 -d test -U username -f /home/camindo/Downloads/person.sql``` I have tried it, and it does not execute

Comment: ```[postgres@fedora ~]$ psql test < person.sql
-bash: person.sql: No such file or directory``` The first code this is its response

Comment: ```[postgres@fedora ~]$ psql test < /home/camindo/Downloads/person.sql
-bash: /home/camindo/Downloads/person.sql: Permission denied```

Comment: You use your own username and host. 5432 is a port number

Comment: `[postgres@fedora ~]$ psql -h localhost -d test -U yourusername -f /home/camindo/Downloads/person.sql`

Comment: Now I see your comment with permission denied. You can run `sudo chmod 777 /home/camindo/Downloads/person.sql` and your issue will be gone

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following command

```
sudo -u username psql -d dbname < "path/backup/backup.sql"
```